# Worst-case recursion depth for guessing numbers in a Sudoku puzzle when certain polynomial-time deduction rules are used

Tags: algorithms, board-games, sudoku

So for an arbitrary $n^2 \times n^2$ Sudoku puzzle, there are rules for inferring values and auxillary information in cells that run in polynomial time, e.g. using the filled in values to check to see if only one number is possible for a cell, using the filled in values to check if only one cell in a given row/column/square can contain a particular number, eliminating a number as a possibility for a row/column outside of a square if the number must lie in the row/column within the square, (and vice-versa for eliminating possibilities within a square), and taking advantage of the fact that if there are $k$ cells in a row/column/square that can only contain a particular subset of $k$ numbers, then no other cells in the row/column/square can contain those numbers. Presumably there are other polynomial time rules too.

The rule/strategy I want to exclude from this list is guessing a fixed number of cells' values, and checking to see if a contradiction is found or a complete valid puzzle is obtained. So, if we consider a certain reasonably rich set of polynomial time rules except for that one, what is the worst-case known recursion depth for how many cells' values need to be guessed simultaneously in order to make progress in a puzzle? Is this known for classical $n = 3$ for a reasonably rich certain set of polynomial time rules (e.g. the rules I listed above), and more interestingly for general $n$?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question.  You know that Sudoko  (for general $n$) is NP-hard, right?  So, no set of polynomial-time rules will be enough to solve this in polynomial time.  Why are you focused on recursion depth?  Recursion depth is a property of a specific algorithm, not a property of the problem.  You can take any recursive algorithm and transform it into one whose recursion depth is $O(1)$ simply by eliminating all recursion (using an explicit stack on the heap instead of using the call stack).  I'm having a hard time extracting a well-posed technical question.

Comment: @D.W. Yes I know that Sudoku is NP-hard. That's why for any set of polynomial-time rules, you will in the worst case have to resort to guessing values for combinations of cells in order to gather more information. I'm asking how many cells' values have to be guessed simultaneously in the worst-case to solve the puzzle, assuming a certain set of polynomial-time rules are used like the rules I listed. This is what I meant by "recursion depth," i.e. one cell value would be guessed at a time and then recurse. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I think this is a well-posed technical Q, albeit difficult.

Comment: OK, good.  Agreed, sounds well-posed but it might be very hard to answer.  For instance, if $P = NP$, then there exists a polynomial-time algorithm to solve it -- which translates into a polynomial-time rule that doesn't require guessing any cells (since any algorithm immediately provides a rule).  Therefore, it looks to me like answering your question for arbitrary rules is as hard as resolving $P$ vs $NP$.  Of course, for a specific set of rules (such as the ones you suggest) maybe it's possible to prove something, but it might be difficult, as you say.